# Convert string to something shorter and unique in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, pack

So I'm currently looking in this ruby implementation:

```
Base64.urlsafe_encode64([Digest::MD5.hexdigest('example.com').to_i(16)].pack("N")).sub(/==\n?$/, '')
```

The example.com string is converted to "SY5Rcg", which is actually the thing that i'm trying to accomplish. Any suggestions? I know that the ruby implementation can not be created in js since the lack of pack method, but that's ok. I'm just looking for something similar.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: It actually has, not native, of course :)) http://phpjs.org/functions/pack:880

Answer (score 0):

That's inherently impossible.

There are fewer shorter-length strings; you cannot guarantee uniquness.